# How to get string data in main form from second from, when button on second form is clicked in C# .net?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

At first I thought that it won't be a problem for me, but now I can't figure it out. So,
when I click Button1 in main form, form2 opens. Form2 is simple numeric keyboard, that user can enter some data. On form2 is also Save. When user clicks it, entered value should pass to main form and from that moment some event must happen in main form, which contains data from form2. Could you please give me some example or any kind of help? Thanks!

```
 // code from main form to create form2
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a new instance of the Form2 class
        Form2 settingsForm = new Form2();

        // Show the settings form
        settingsForm.Show();

        string val = settingsForm.ReturnValue1;            

        MessageBox.Show(val);
    }

//button save on form2
private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ReturnValue1 = "Something";
        this.ReturnValue2 = DateTime.Now.ToString(); //example
        this.Close();
        //after this, some event should happen in main form !
    }
```

Comment: what you  have tried post some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here a sample how you  can achieve this

//here I suppose that form1 is the mainform

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void UpdateMainForm(string updatedString)
        {
            //here you can update  and invoke methods
             //Once called you could raise events in your mainform 


        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Form2 form2 = new Form2(this))
            {
                form2.ShowDialog();

            }
        }

    }
```

**Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private Form1 _mainForm1; 
        public Form2(Form1  mainForm1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _mainForm1 = mainForm1; 
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _mainForm1.UpdateMainForm( DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of solutions to do what you want; but I think one of these will resolve your problem.

**1-** Simple and easy: use public properties in `Form2`, initialize them when `buttonSave` get clicked, and access them in `Form1`:

*Form2:*

```
public partial class Form2 : Form {
    public Form2() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        YourDate = "something";
        Close();
    }

    public object YourDate { get; private set; }
}
```

*Form1:*

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        var f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog();
        var data = f2.YourDate;
    }
}
```

**2-** A better way, is using events which is more flexible and professional programming friendly:

*Form2:*

```
public partial class Form2 : Form {

    public Form2() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // create an event of Action<T> which T is your data-type. e.g. in this example I use an object. 
    public event Action<object> SaveClicked;

    // create an event invocator, to invoke event whenever you want
    protected virtual void OnSaveClicked(object data){
        var handler = SaveClicked;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(data);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        // prepare your data here, -object, or string, or int, or whatever it is
        var data = PrepareYourDataHere;
        // invoke the event
        OnSaveClicked(data);
        Close();
    }
}
```

*Form1:*

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        // create an instance of Form2
        var f2 = new Form2();
        // add an event listener to SaveClicked event -which we have declared it in Form2
        f2.SaveClicked += f2_SaveClicked;
        f2.Show();
        // or: f2.ShowDialog();
    }

    void f2_SaveClicked(object obj) {
        // get data and use it here...
        // any data which you pass in Form2.OnSaveClicked method, will be accessible here
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to fire some events in form1, just after form2 closed, you can simply add a listener to `Form2.FormClosed` event:

```
// code from main form to create form2
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Create a new instance of the Form2 class
    Form2 settingsForm = new Form2();
    settingsForm.FormClosed += SettingFormClosed;

    // Show the settings form
    settingsForm.Show();

    string val = settingsForm.ReturnValue1;            

    MessageBox.Show(val);
}

void SettingFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) {
    // this method will be called automatically when form2 closed
}
```